# SAP HANA - Some services not started

Tags: sap

SAP HANA was configured correct and SAP HANA Studio was connected to SAP HANA.

From one day to another SAP HANA is not reachable in the SAP HANA Studio.

The operational state is "Some services not started"

How to fix this?
(I have an systems operation account on the HANA server)

[image: Systems view]

[image: System monitor]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by restarting SAP HANA

```
/usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/sapcontrol -nr 00 -function RestartSystem ALL
```

Comment: there is a nuclear option for every problem, right ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since restarting the whole database is not always an option, there is a better way:

1) check which service exactly is not running (e.g., in SAP HANA Studio, right click the system --> Configuration and Monitoring --> Open Administration; there in the 'Landscape' tab you are usually able to see which services are not running)

2) start missing services (starting them from the 'Landscape' tab usually does not work, so you could do it from console of your server):

- go to the folder of your instance, e.g. `/usr/sap/XDB/XDB01/`
- `su - <xdb>adm` (where `<xdb>adm` is the admin user of your instance)
- start missing service, e.g. `exe/hdbnameserver &`